# Sorting a range of numbers - In place

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to solve the following question :

> We are given an array containing ‘n’ objects. Each object, when created, was assigned a unique number from 1 to ‘n’ based on their creation sequence. This means that the object with sequence number ‘3’ was created just before the object with sequence number ‘4’.

> Write a function to sort the objects in-place on their creation sequence number in O(n)O(n) and without any extra space. For simplicity, let’s assume we are passed an integer array containing only the sequence numbers, though each number is actually an object.

Eg :
Input : [2, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5]
Output : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

My approach :

```cpp
void sortInPlace(int *arr,int n){

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        if(arr[i] != arr[arr[i]-1]){
            swap(arr[i],arr[arr[i]-1]);
        }
    }


}

int main(){

    int n;
    cout<<"\n Enter number of elements:";
    cin>>n;

    int arr[n];
    cout<<"\n Enter the elements :";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    sortInPlace(arr,n);

    cout<<"\n Sorted Array :";
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){

        cout<<arr[i];
    }

}
```

But, this doesn't produce the right results.

Actual solution :

[image]

The only difference I could find is the While loop that they have used.

The while loop in the solution has an extra iteration to increment the 'i' , whereas , My solution does it in a for loop without requiring additional iterations.

Example : My approach

```
Input : [1,5,6,4,3,2]
Output : [1,3,2,4,5,6]
Expected output : [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

But, why doesn't it work ? Could someone please tell me if I am missing something ?

Comment: Your friend and mine The Debugger is very helpful here. Step through both programs with small input sets and watch where the behaviours diverge.

Comment: Thanks ! I have edited my question

Comment: @BharathiA "_Thanks ! I have edited my question_" But.. Did you, actually, follow the advice in a comment, of stepping through both solutions, with a debugger?

Answer (score 5):

On every iteration of `for (int i=0; i < n; i++)`, `i` is incremented.

The `while` loop only increments `i` if no swap was made.

To get the same behaviour, the `for` version must not increment `i` when a swap is made.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @user4581301, another approach can be in your solution - having a while loop instead of if condition. I think Time Complexity will be same even if we are adding while loop inside for because of condition in while loop. As while loop will get executed if condition is true. I came up with this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuAzd.png)

Comment: It should be comment, not an answer.

Comment: @HirenPatel-As you can see, I have mentioned another approach, I think it should be answer, not a comment.